# How to detect if PIN/password/pattern is required to unlock phone?

Tags: android, locking, unlock

How can I detect if the phone is locked by a password, pin or pattern?

thank you!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Two methods

1. Check programatically - API 16+

https://gist.github.com/doridori/54c32c66ef4f4e34300f

*Note that you dont need to check for face unlock as that requires that a pin/pass fallback is set.*

2. Device Admin Policies

Can also look into the Device Admin Policies which allow restrictions on how the app is setup regarding security including pin/pass set restrictions

- [Device Administration](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/admin/device-admin.html)
- [Enhancing Security with Device Management Policies](https://developer.android.com/training/enterprise/device-management-policy.html)

As an aside, these are the lock types you want to check for if using an encrypted `Keystore`. Check [here](http://doridori.github.io/android-security-the-forgetful-keystore/) for more info.

Comment: Seems like you can check for all three lock types through the Keyguard now "LOCK_PATTERN_ENABLED - This constant was deprecated in API level 23. Use KeyguardManager to determine the state and security level of the keyguard. Accessing this setting from an app that is targeting M or later throws a SecurityException." http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.Secure.html

Comment: Your right. [KeyGuardManager.isKeyGuardSecure()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/KeyguardManager.html#isKeyguardSecure()) now returns _"true if a PIN, pattern or password is set or a SIM card is locked."_ since 23

Comment: @Don Do you mean that prior to 23 isKeyguardSecure did not return true when the device was locked with a pattern ? That's not what the documentation says. And it would be a pretty dumb thing to do. It would appear that isKeyguardSecure always returned true for PIN, pattern or password, since API 16 when it was introduced. I did test it on 19 and this is what it does.

Comment: @Don So your github code seems too complex for API 16+, isPatternSet is redundant. I gave an answer with a simpler version.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the [Settings.Secure](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.Secure.html) class to query information about the security in place on an android device. For example, to see if the user has a lock pattern enabled you'd do:

```
ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
int lockPatternEnable = 
  Settings.Secure.getInt(cr, Settings.Secure.LOCK_PATTERN_ENABLED);
```

`lockPatternEnable` would then have a 0 if it wasn't enabled and a 1 if it was enabled.

Comment: Won't that only give you if lock pattern enabled but not if Pin enabled.  I have both Pin and Pattern on my phone, and its actually 2 different states.

Comment: Hmmm. I'll have to do some more research. For now it looks like we only know how to check if the Lock patter is enabled.

Comment: but i am getting exception saying 12-26 17:25:39.176:  android.provider.Settings$SettingNotFoundException: lock_pattern_autolock..may i know how to resolve it

Comment: [KeyguardManager.isKeyguardSecure()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/KeyguardManager.html#isKeyguardSecure()) will be true if a pin or password is set

Comment: `lockPatternEnable` is giving out 0 even when its set in `Moto G5 Plus` !! Any ideas how this can be resolved ?

Comment: [It looks like this was depreciated in api 23](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.Secure.html#LOCK_PATTERN_VISIBLE)

Answer (score 5):

This should be OK for Android API 16 and up, according to the documentation. I tested it on 19 and it seems to work.

```
private boolean IsDeviceSecured () {
    KeyguardManager keyguardManager =
            (KeyguardManager) getSystemService(Context.KEYGUARD_SERVICE); //api 16+
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        return keyguardManager.isDeviceSecure();
    }
    return keyguardManager.isKeyguardSecure ();
}
```