# How do I access the password type settings of an Android device?

Tags: android

I'm trying to access my devices password type settings and am getting a SettingNotFoundException even though the device does have a lock PIN set.

I have tried using the LockPatternUtils suggested in this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7768879/check-whether-lock-was-enabled-or-not) but it does not work.

Here is basically what I'm doing (and what LockPatternUtils does):

```
    try {
        result = android.provider.Settings.Secure.getLong(
                mContentResolver, "lockscreen.password_type");
    } catch (SettingNotFoundException e) {
        Log.d("Cannot get key", "cannot get long value", e);
    }
```

This is where the SettingNotFoundException occurs since it obviously cannot find that setting.

Here is the kicker. I'm testing this on 2 different devices. One has a password of 6 characters and the other has a PIN of 4 characters. The first has Android 4.1.2 and the other 4.2.1. It works fine on the first one that's running on 4.1.2

Thank you!

Comment: Since that is not a documented setting, you are unrealistic in expecting it to work reliably across devices and OS versions. In particular, on 4.2, that's likely a per-user value.

Comment: Do you know of any other method or methods to gain access to this information? Particularly whether or not the device is using a password or PIN and it's length?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are welcome to get information about password quality and such [via `DevicePolicyManager`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/admin/DevicePolicyManager.html) and the device admin APIs.

Comment: Hey I have a device running on 4.1.2 with a 4 digit PIN. mDevicePolicyManager.getPasswordQuality(adminComponent) is returning 0 every time. Any ideas?

Comment: @bsimic: `getPasswordQuality()` tells you what the *requested* password quality is, based on the individual requests of all password managers. My memory failed me when I wrote my answer, as you cannot find out a ton about the current password via the device admin APIs. You can call `isActivePasswordSufficient()` if you want, though this will require you to be an active device admin, and it will simply tell you if the current password meets the current password requirements.

Comment: Since getPasswordQuality() is returning 0, wouldn't isActivePasswordSufficient() always return true? I'm really trying to just figure out if the device is locked using a password or PIN without having to set the device lock setting myself.

Comment: @bsimic: "Since getPasswordQuality() is returning 0, wouldn't isActivePasswordSufficient() always return true?" -- you'd need to temporarily change the password rules, to see if the current password matched those rules.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up. It's my first time messing with Android Device Policy stuff. I appreciate your time!

Comment: I actually ended up using keyguardManager.isKeyguardSecure() to check if the user is using a password or PIN. Seems to work just fine.

Comment: @CommonsWare Is there any alternative to using DevicePolicyManager? Registering our app as device admin, is risky. Since the user can anytime goto settings and remove our app from device admin.

Comment: @LoveForDroid: "Registering our app as device admin, is risky" -- you should not need to register as a device admin. `DevicePolicyManager` methods for *reading* the password quality should be available for all apps. *Changing* the password quality requires being a device admin.