# Android 4.3 : How can I check if user has lock enabled?

Tags: android, security, locking

I want my app to behave differently (not store stuff) if the user does not have a lock screen or only swipe enabled.
The top answer here: [check whether lock was enabled or not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7768879/check-whether-lock-was-enabled-or-not) has been edited to say the code no longer works after upgrade to Android 4.3.

Is there anyway to detect this on Android 4.3?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ok, so it seems it is possible with some reflection. Not the best solution, but at least it works on the devices we tried:

```
        Class<?> clazz = Class.forName("com.android.internal.widget.LockPatternUtils");
        Constructor<?> constructor = clazz.getConstructor(Context.class);
        constructor.setAccessible(true);
        Object utils = constructor.newInstance(context);
        Method method = clazz.getMethod("isSecure");
        return (Boolean)method.invoke(utils);
```

Comment: Please note that this won't work with Android 6.x or 7.

Comment: Yeah, using reflection like that is a hack that I expected to break at some point. Do you know how to do it on those versions?

Comment: Sure , take a look at https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/KeyguardManager.html. For Android 5.0 and up it does the job.

Comment: Thanks, @FunkSoulBrother!

Answer (score 5):

You can check it with KeyguardManager:

```
KeyguardManager keyguardMgr = (KeyguardManager) getSystemService(Context.KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
if(keyguardMgr.isKeyguardSecure()){
    // Secure keyguard, the keyguard requires a password to unlock
} else {
    // Insecure keyguard, the keyguard doesn't require a password to unlock
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check with KeyguardManager's method `isKeyguardSecure()` to make sure if lock or passcode is enabled or not.

```
KeyguardManager keyguardManager = (KeyguardManager) getSystemService(KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
        Toast.makeText(this,"KeyGuardEnabled ? "+ keyguardManager.isKeyguardSecure(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```