# Get the current screen lock mode on Android

Tags: android, screen

Is there a way to get the current screen lock mode on Android programmatically? PIN, pattern, password, etc.

Comment: What ? I didn't get what exactly you want to know

Comment: do you mean allways landscape or something like that? i cant understand your question

Comment: [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18720287/3436942) (i think this is what you're looking for anyway)