# Check if a phone has a PIN code

Tags: android, iphone, mobile

I apologise for the cross platform nature of this post. My query is related to Android and iOS mobile phones only.

My company is looking at building a mobile app. One of the features suggested by a stakeholder is for the app to know/detect if the phone has a PIN code. For the sake of clarifying, I am referring to PIN code as the code the user enters to unlock the device and use it.

The suggestion is that the app should warn/refuse access to a particular function if the phone does not have a PIN code. The business driver is that the phone needs to be more secure in order to use the app.

We have not looked at potential frameworks for development and its likely that we may even go native. My first port of call is to understand if the above mentioned check is even possible?

Answer (score 1):

### Android

Yes, this is possible. But on devices with an API level lower than 23 (M) these Methods involve accessing private fields (=are not official).

Starting with API 23 it is as simple as calling [`KeyguardManager.isDeviceSecure()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/KeyguardManager.html#isDeviceSecure()).

All this is covered in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7768879/check-whether-lock-was-enabled-or-not).